# Knockout : Unusual Mapping Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Scenario:   I make a request to the server for a part.   It gives me this back (it's pseudo, but represents what I'm looking at):

```
{
PartNumber : "XYZ", 
Description: "ABCFOO", 
ProductClass: "Widget",
FieldList:[
    {Name: "PROGRAM TYPE", Value: "Program3"},
    {Name: "SHIP", Value: false},
    {Name: "NOTES", Value: "SomeValue1"}
],
MoreStuff : [{
    ...
}]
}
```

Note the FieldList list of elements, that's the focus here.

The server also gave me a list of certain fields, their types and default values. It looks like this:

```
[
{FieldName : "PROGRAM TYPE", FieldType: "List", Defaults: [{Name:"Program 1", Value: "Program1"},{Name:"Program 2", Value: "Program2"},{Name:"Program 3", Value: "Program3"}]},
{FieldName : "SHIP", FieldType : "Boolean", Defaults: []},
{FieldName : "NOTES", FieldType: "TextArea", Defaults: []}
]
```

That comes in a seperate REST call, and the prior to loading my Part.   I use it to create part of the HTML page for the Part.   You can see they're similarly related to the `FieldList` section from when I ask for Part.

From that "list of fields" and defaults -- I generate the appropriate HTML elements on the page.    If it's a Boolean field type, I create a checkbox - if it's a list, I create a SELECT (with options given in Defaults), TextArea is a text-area, etc.   That all works fine.     It ends up looking like:

```
<input data-bind="textInput: PartNumber"/>
<textarea data-bind="textInput: Description"></textarea>

<!-- generating fieldlist - i create a pseudo attr because the field name can have spaces-->
<select field_label="PROGRAM TYPE">   <!-- how the heck do i bind to this??-->
   <option value="Program1">Program 1</option>
   <option value="Program2">Program 2</option>
   <option value="Program3">Program 3</option>
</select >
<input type="checkbox" field_label="SHIP" value="true"/> <!-- or this, how to bind to it?!-->
<!-- end of field list generation -->
```

Now I take the object (the part I'm given) and put that into my ViewModel - that is all working just swimmingly.   I make it easy and just use `ko.mapping.fromJS(rest_data);`  Works just fine.

Data binding is ducky -- for what I am able to bind it to.    My issue comes from -- *how the heck do I map my `FieldList` to the HTML I generated for the fields the server gave me?*.    My data / my viewmodel object has `FieldList` in it, with a buncha stuff I want to map to that generated stuff.  The only real "key" I have is the self-created `field_label` I have, because the server's `FieldName` can have spaces.

So I guess what I'm asking is, I have that array of `FieldList` from my part.   I have the whole Part object in my view model and it's all fine.    How do I take that `FieldList` and map it into my self-generated set of fields from the other object (**ie., take the FieldList name and tie it to the element with `field_label` of the same value?**)

Spelled out - it'd be like:    How to map `FieldList` with Name of "PROGRAM TYPE" to HTML element having field_label of "PROGRAM TYPE".

I begin to think something like this might be the direction I should be going:
http://jsfiddle.net/MhdZp/128/
but it goes over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this:

```
function Option(definition) {
    this.definition = definition;
    this.value = ko.observable();
    this.templateName = 'input-template-' + definition.FieldType;
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // from REST call
    var fieldDefinition = [{
        FieldName: "PROGRAM TYPE",
        FieldType: "List",
        Defaults: [
            { Name: "Program 1", Value: "Program1" }, 
            { Name: "Program 2", Value: "Program2" }, 
            { Name: "Program 3", Value: "Program3" }
        ]
    }];

    self.options = ko.observableArray();
    // for the sake of the example
    self.options.push(new Option(fieldDefinition[0]));

    // methods    
    self.optionByName = function (name) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.options(), function (option) {
            return option.Name = name;
        });
    };

    // poor man's init, imagine 2nd rest call instead
    self.optionByName("PROGRAM TYPE").value("Program3");
}
```

and

```html
<script type="text/html" id="input-template-List">
    <label data-bind="text: definition.FieldName"></label>
    <select data-bind="
        value: value,
        options: definition.Defaults,
        optionsText: 'Name',
        optionsValue: 'Value',
        optionsCaption: 'Please select...'
    "></select>
</script>
```

and

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: options">
  <div data-bind="template: templateName"></div>
</div>
```

Add more templates as needed, this should be very easy to extend.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0nxt2zte/

Comment: I might be mistaking something here, but it looks like the ViewModel was wrapped around the object for the HTML elements I generate (the second JSON) -- wherein the ViewModel I have is wrapped around the first JSON object I get (my Part).    Am I reading your code wrong?   Sorry, a bit frazzled, today's a hectic one.

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time parsing your comment. :) Have you looked at the fiddle?

Comment: From what I understand it goes like this: **1)** You receive a bunch of field definitions. **2)** Next you create a bunch of input elements according to these definitions. **3)** You receive a bunch of "selected values" via Ajax and want to bind your inputs to them. That's exactly how my code works.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to punch that all out for me.  I appreciate it!

Comment: It works the way you did it.  I wasn't originally putting the defaults inside the ViewModel (just drawing them) - but doing as you did made it work for me.   I've yet to understand KO beyond the basics, so this really helped out.  The fun part is tearing it apart, so I *can* understand it and use it again later.   Really, thanks.

Comment: Good to hear. Putting the defaults into the ViewModel is not necessary, as indicated they ought to be fetched via Ajax. But I can see why you're having difficulties. See this modified Fiddle which uses Ajax requests for both parts (field definitions and fields). It extends my answer with the necessary bits for dealing with multiple async requests. (Highly recommended reading: jQuery deferreds). http://jsfiddle.net/0nxt2zte/1/

Comment: @Jason And while we're at it: How to request definitions only once but data multiple times and a few other bells and whistles. http://jsfiddle.net/0nxt2zte/2/

Comment: I wish more folks could lay eyes on this answer -- it's such a solid answer with full-code to back it up.    It deserves more than just my click on it.  :-/

Comment: Ahh, never mind. In time, someone will come by and draw some benefit from it. If it helped you that's enough.